# Добавление булевых значений в массив

Tags: javascript

Есть задача:
Создай функцию checkNumber, которая принимает целое число number и проверяет его по трем различым свойствам:

```
это число положительное?
это число четное?
это число кратно 10?
```

Функция должна вернуть массив с результатами проверок в виде булевых значений.

мой код:

```
function checkNumber(number) {

  let x = [0];
  let y = [0];
  let s = [0];
  let result = []



  if (number > 0) {
    x += number;
    result.push(x)
  }

  if (number % 2 == 0) {
    y += number;
    result.push(y)
  }
  if (number === 10) {
    s += number;
    result.push(s)
  }
  return result;

}
```

что только не перепробовал, в массив не заходят эти значения.

Comment: Точно этот же вопрос уже был, щас найду, если не было удалено, конечно....

Comment: было бы отлично)

Comment: Видимо всё же удалили... Либо я плохо ищу. Просто я уверен на все 100% что уже отвечал на этот вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const checkNumber = (num) => [
  num > 0,
  num % 2 === 0,
  num % 10 === 0,
];

console.log(checkNumber(1));
console.log(checkNumber(-1));
console.log(checkNumber(4));
console.log(checkNumber(-20));
```

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло!